# How to create a list from a dict of lists that has combinations of the array elements

Tags: python, list, dictionary, combinations

The question might have been worded confusingly so here I will try to make it more clear. Suppose I have a dict like `x = {0: [(36, 44)], 1: [(38, 39), (38, 40), (39, 40)], 2: [(37, 41), (37, 42), (41, 42)], 3: [(43,)], 4: [(45,)]}`

I want to create a list with all possible combinations of 1 element from each of the array. E.g. - `[(36,44),(38,39),(37,41),(43),(45)]` is one such combination, `[(36,44),(38,40),(37,41),(43),(45)]` is another. The final list should have all such combinations.

For now as I know the key values, I tried doing it as

```
arr_0 = x[0]

arr_1 = x[1]

arr_2 = x[2]

arr_3 = x[3]

arr_4 = x[4]
```

and then finally,

`y = itertools.product(arr_0, arr_1, arr_2, arr_3, arr_4)`

which produces the answer

```
((36, 44), (38, 39), (37, 41), (43,), (45,))

((36, 44), (38, 39), (37, 42), (43,), (45,))

((36, 44), (38, 39), (41, 42), (43,), (45,))

((36, 44), (38, 40), (37, 41), (43,), (45,))

((36, 44), (38, 40), (37, 42), (43,), (45,))

((36, 44), (38, 40), (41, 42), (43,), (45,))

((36, 44), (39, 40), (37, 41), (43,), (45,))

((36, 44), (39, 40), (37, 42), (43,), (45,))

((36, 44), (39, 40), (41, 42), (43,), (45,))
```

In a scenario where I do not the keys of the dict and the array sizes, how can I create the final array ?

Comment: It'd be highly advisable to show an honest attempt of yours *along* with the question.

Comment: @baduker added my attempt, the question should be clearer for everyone now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `itertools.product` and pass it the different arrays thta you need

```
from itertools import product

x = {0: [(36, 44)], 1: [(38, 39), (38, 40), (39, 40)], 2: [(37, 41), (37, 42)]}

for p in product(*x.values()):
    print(p)

((36, 44), (38, 39), (37, 41))
((36, 44), (38, 39), (37, 42))
((36, 44), (38, 40), (37, 41))
((36, 44), (38, 40), (37, 42))
((36, 44), (39, 40), (37, 41))
((36, 44), (39, 40), (37, 42))
```

The `x.values()` is a list of list of values (tuples) `[[(36, 44)], [(38, 39), (38, 40), (39, 40)], [(37, 41), (37, 42)]]`, the `*` is here to expand them and pass each sublist a different parameter of the method

---

For you to get it, a smaller example

```
for p in product([1, 2], [3], (5, 6)):
    print(p)
    
(1, 3, 5)
(1, 3, 6)
(2, 3, 5)
(2, 3, 6)
```

Comment: After `*` expands, how are the individual sublist still preserved ? afaik, I `*` unpacks everything to a single dimension.

Comment: @user3656142 * doesn’t reduce to 1 dimension, it reduce OF 1 dimension, so you keep different sublists , each one with 1 or more tuples